# StoreKit Products Request didFailWithError called before didReceiveResponse

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm experiencing an issue in my app where the `didFailWithError` callback is called immediately after calling `start` on my products request, before it's followed by a successful `didReceiveResponse` callback.

The error provided in the `didFailWithError` is:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

This is an issue because I rely on the `didFailWithError` to provide me with an accurate update on the products request, and update my UI accordingly. Once this is fired, I would like to cancel my products request and display that information to the user. If I do so, I never get the successful reply afterward. If I simply ignore the `didFailWithError`, I am unable to provide my users with an update if it actually did fail.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue? If so, is this a known bug Apple is working on, or is this due to an error on my part? Are there any workarounds you have been able to use instead?

Comment: Is the `NSError` object nil, or what is the error?

Comment: @MikeTaverne sorry, seems like I forgot to include the error. I have updated the question. The error is an NSError object with the following structure `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"`